# Why is a complex string (stringified json data) not accepted as a POST parameter to a Web API method, but a simple string is?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, http-post, asp.net-web-api-routing

I want to send a bunch of data, converted to json, as a string, to a Web API POST method. I can send a simple string just fine, but when I try to send stringified json data, the method is not even reached - apparently the complex string is not viewed as a valid string value or something.

This works, when passing "randomString" from the client:

### Web API

```
[Route("{unit}/{begindate}/{enddate}/{stringifiedjsondata}")]
[HttpPost]
public void Post(string unit, string begindate, string enddate, string stringifiedjsondata)
{
    // test
    string jsonizedData = stringifiedjsondata;
```

### WinForms

```
string dataAsJson = "randomString";
String uriToCall = String.Format("/api/produceusage/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}", _unit, beginRange, endRange, dataAsJson);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uriToCall, null);
```

When the string is json data, such as this:

```
[
  {
    "ItemDescription": "DUCKBILLS, GRAMPS-EIER 70CT  42#",
    "PackagesMonth1": 1467, . . . }]
```

...it does not work. I create this string by converting a generic list to json using JSON.NET like so:

```
string dataAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_rawAndCalcdDataAmalgamatedList, Formatting.Indented);
String uriToCall = String.Format("/api/produceusage/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}", _unit, beginRange, endRange, dataAsJson);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uriToCall, null);
```

So the only difference is in the string; when it's something simple like "randomString" I reach this line in the Web API POST method:

```
string jsonizedData = stringifiedjsondata;
```

...but when it's a complex string, such as stringified json data, that line is not reached.

Why? And how can I fix the stringified json data so that it is received and recognized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having troubles because you are sending the JSON to your API through the URL. I suggest you to send it in the body content of your request. In order to do it, change your Web Api method like this:

```
[Route("{unit}/{begindate}/{enddate}")]
[HttpPost]
public void Post(string unit, string begindate, string enddate, [FromBody] string stringifiedjsondata)
{
    // test
    string jsonizedData = stringifiedjsondata;
}
```

Also change your Winforms client code:

```
string dataAsJson = "[{\"ItemDescription\": \"DUCKBILLS, GRAMPS-EIER 70CT  42#\",\"PackagesMonth1\": 1467}]";
String uriToCall = String.Format("/api/produceusage/{0}/{1}/{2}", _unit, beginRange, endRange);
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", dataAsJson)
});

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uriToCall, content);
```

Now it should work as you expected. Check this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) about the HTTP Client library in order to see more examples about sending data to an API if you need it.

Comment: A related question will be bountified ASAP here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138361/how-can-i-pass-a-moderately-large-volume-of-data-to-my-web-api-app