# Why is my REST method not being called by this jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, rest, controller

I have a similar question about jQuery button click handler code not being fired at all [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258662/why-is-my-jquery-button-handler-not-being-fired).

In this case, it *is* being fired (when the jQuery is added to a static page (Index.cshtml)), but my REST method is still not being reached. The console message explaining why is:

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /LandingPage/GetQuadrantData

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0
```

This is the jQuery, which indeed gets fired when the button is clicked, but the REST call is not being made:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var btnGetData = document.getElementById('btnGetData');
        btnGetData.addEventListener("click", function () {
            alert("It works");
            var unitval = 'ABUELOS';
            var begdateval = '2016-08-07';
            var enddateval = '2016-08-13';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetQuadrantData", "LandingPage")',
                data: { unit: unitval, begdate: begdateval, enddate: enddateval },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (returneddata) {
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('hey, boo-boo!');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The REST method is set up like so, in LandingPageController.cs:

```
[Route("{unit}/{begdate}/{enddate}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetQuadrantData(string unit, string begdate, string enddate)
{
    _unit = unit;
    _beginDate = begdate;
    _endDate = enddate;
    . . .
```

I have a breakpoint on the "_unit = unit;" line, but it is not being reached; why not? What am I missing here?

The REST controller class under discussion begins like so:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class LandingPageController : ApiController
```

Note: If I use this in the jQuery ("Controller" appended):

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetQuadrantData", "LandingPageController")'
```

...both "GetQuadrantData" and "LandingPageController" are red in the IDE (Visual Studio) editor - the letters are red.

OTOH, if I use this (sans "Controller" appended):

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetQuadrantData", "LandingPage")'
```

(which has worked for me in the past, leaving the "Controller" off the Controller name), both "GetQuadrantData" and  "LandingPage" are UNDERLINED in red, but the font remains the normal color.

### UPDATE

Using Nico's link in his comment below, I changed the jQuery "url" line to this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetQuadrantData", "LandingPage", new { httproute = "" })',
```

...but it still didn't cause the Controller method to be reached.

### UPDATE 2

Stepping through the javascript in the (Chrome) browser, I see that the "url" line has been dynamically changed from what it is at design time:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetQuadrantData", "LandingPage", new { httproute = "" })',
```

...to:

```
url: '/api/LandingPage?action=GetQuadrantData',
```

I reckon what it should really have been resolved to is more like:

```
url: '/api/ABUELOS/2016-08-14/2016-08-20',
```

Am I right? Why isn't it being resolved like so?

If I manually enter that URL in the browser, so that the URL bar reads "`http://localhost:52194/api/ABUELOS/2016-08-21/2016-08-27`" it works - the method is reached and it "does its thing."

### UPDATE 3

I tried this, too:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnGetData").click(function () {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetQuadrantData", "LandingPage")',
            success: function (retval) {
                $("body").append($(retval));
                document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error in btnGetData');
            }
        }); // end AJAX
    }); // end click
}); // end ready function
```

...but only saw "error in btnGetData"

### UPDATE 4

My most recent failure is this:

```
$("#btnGetData").click(function () {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
    var unitval = $('#unitName').val();
    var begdateval = $('#datepickerFrom').val();
    var enddateval = $('#datepickerTo').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetQuadrantData", "LandingPage")',
        data: { unit: unitval, begdate: begdateval, enddate: enddateval },
        cache: false,
        success: function (returneddata) {
            alert($(returneddata));
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error in ajax');
        }
    });
});
```

Again, I see only "error in ajax"

### UPDATE 5

**Note**: The maximum bounty (200 points, I think it is) will be awarded to whoever can solve this dilemma. If more than one person does, then the bounty goes to whoever solves it best (which basically to me means in the most straightforward and easy-to-implement manner.

In the interest of full disclosure and desperation, here is the entire contents (with boring/meaningless parts elided with ellipsis dots) of the first page that displays when the WEB API app runs (from \Views\Home\Index.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>eServices Reporting - Customer Dashboard</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            background-color: white;
        }
    . . .
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnGetData").click(function () {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
            var unitval = "ABUELOS"; //$('#unitName').val();
            var begdateval = $('#datepickerFrom').val();
            var enddateval = $('#datepickerTo').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetQuadrantData", "LandingPage")',
                data: { unit: unitval, begdate: begdateval, enddate: enddateval },
                cache: false,
                success: function (returneddata) {
                    alert($(returneddata));
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error in ajax');
                }
            });
        });

    }); // end ready function
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <div class="jumbotronjr">
            <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top: 0.6cm">
                <img src="http://www.proactusa.com/wp-content/themes/proact/images/pa_logo_notag.png" height="86" width="133" alt="PRO*ACT usa logo">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <label class="titletext" style="margin-top: 0.2cm;">Customer Dashboard</label>
                <br />
                <label class="titletextjr" style="margin-top: -2.2cm;" id="unitName">Craftworks</label>
                <label class="cccsfont"> for the week of August 14          </label>
                <input class="smalldatepicker" type="date" id="datepickerFrom" name="daterangefrom" value="2016-08-14">
                </input>
                <label class="cccsfont"> to </label>
                <input type="date" class="smalldatepicker" id="datepickerTo" name="daterangeto" value="2016-08-20">
                </input>
                <button class="btn green smallbutton" id="btnGetData" name="btnGetData">SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>    

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>    

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="topleft">
                    <h2 class="sectiontext">Top 10 Items Purchased</h2>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Item Code</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th class="rightjustifytext">Qty</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>101200</td>
                            <td>ASPARAGUS, STANDARD 11/1#</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>140200</td>
                            <td>MUSHROOMS, MEDIUM 10#</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">20</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>140000</td>
                            <td>MUSHROOMS, BUTTON 10#</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">14</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>127100</td>
                            <td>LETTUCE, ROMAINE 24 CT </td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">14</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>300123</td>
                            <td>BEANS, GREEN TRIM 2/5# (BAGS)</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">13</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>173100</td>
                            <td>POTATOES,  50 CT IDAHO</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">12</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>234225</td>
                            <td>BERRIES, STRAWBERRY 1# CLAM</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">11</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>188500</td>
                            <td>TOMATOES, GRAPE 12/1 PT</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">10</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>122500</td>
                            <td>LETTUCE, ICEBERG LINER 24 CT</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">10</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>121050</td>
                            <td>LETTUCE, GREEN LEAF 24 CT</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">10</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="topright">
                    <h2 class="sectiontext">Pricing Exceptions - Weekly Recap</h2>
                    <label class="redfont cccs">Red denotes Contract Item Overages</label>
                    </br>
                    <label class="cccs">For Weyand on the pricing week of - 7/31/2016</label>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>PRO*ACT Member</th>
                            <th class="rightjustifytext">Total Occurrences of Summary Items</th>
                            <th class="rightjustifytext">Total Summary Exceptions</th>
                            <th class="rightjustifytext">Total Percentage of Summary Exceptions</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:30%">Stern</td>
                            <td style="width:23%" class="rightjustifytext">205</td>
                            <td style="width:23%" class="rightjustifytext">2</td>
                            <td style="width:24%" class="rightjustifytext">99.02%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hardies Dallas</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">1,597</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">0</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">100.00%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hardies South</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">612</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">1</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">99.84%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Go Fresh</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">482</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">0</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">100.00%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Segovias</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">1,360</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">2</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">99.85%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Potato Spec</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">1,605</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">0</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">100.00%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext bold">TOTAL</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext bold">5,861</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext bold">5</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext bold">99.79%</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="bottomleft">
                    <h2 class="sectiontext">Forecasted Spend - $9,814.81</h2>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Item Code</th>
                            <th class="rightjustifytext">Last Week's Usage</th>
                            <th class="rightjustifytext">This Week's Price</th>
                            <th class="rightjustifytext">Forecasted Spend</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>261650</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">49</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">3.14</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">153.86</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>231083</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">52</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">1.25</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">65.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>398980</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">46</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">4.95</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">227.70</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>351135</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">40</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">0.75</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">30.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>398036</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">42</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">3.00</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">126.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>208110</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">42</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">2.50</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">105.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>102800</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">1835</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">2.25</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">4,128.75</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>367050</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">1910</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">1.95</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">3,724.50</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>173100</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">66</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">19.00</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">1,254.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="bold">TOTAL</td>
                            <td class="bold rightjustifytext">4082</td>
                            <td class="bold rightjustifytext">--</td>
                            <td class="bold rightjustifytext">$9,814.81</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="bottomright">
                    <h2 class="sectiontext">Delivery Performance</h2>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>PRO*ACT Distributor</th>
                            <th>Restaurant Location</th>
                            <th class="rightjustifytext">Avg Order Amount</th>
                            <th class="rightjustifytext">Avg Package Count</th>
                            <th class="rightjustifytext">Total Sales</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Sunrise FL</td>
                            <td>A1A ALEWORKS - #4405 - ST. AUGUSTINE</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">$475.78</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">28.50</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">$1,903.10</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sunrise FL</td>
                            <td>RAGTIME TAVERN - #4404 - ATLANTIC BEACH</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">$221.46</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">17.50</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">$885.82</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sunrise FL</td>
                            <td>SEVEN BRIDGES - #4403 - JACKSONVILLE</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">$367.49</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">22.67</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">$1,102.47</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>T&T</td>
                            <td>BIG RIVER - #4201 - CHATTANOOGA</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">$396.06</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">22.83</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">$2,376.34</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>T&T</td>
                            <td>BIG RIVER - #4205 - HAMILTON PL</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">$424.74</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">26.00</td>
                            <td class="rightjustifytext">$1,698.95</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="bold">TOTAL</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="bold rightjustifytext">3,770.42</td>
                            <td class="bold rightjustifytext">23.50</td>
                            <td class="bold rightjustifytext">$1,592.60</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

### UPDATE 6

I know there's more to Arturo's answer than this, but so far just adding this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "QuadrantData",
    routeTemplate: "api/{unit}/{begdate}/{enddate}"
);
```

...has helped, as the breakpoint in my method is being reached. Unfortunately, it squawks "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17861208/1210053) help you?

Comment: Not really - it changes it, but I still don't reach the breakpoint in the Controller method. It's changed in that I don't see the "boo-boo" message until I stop the process - I just see the "it works" alert at first.

Comment: So the request is now succeeding (i.e. you get the correct URL now)? Is the controller doing a lot of work (maybe an infinite loop) that prevents it from returning? Not hitting the breakpoint is not a definite proof for not working.

Comment: Since I have the breakpoint on the first line of the method, it seems to me it's not being reached.

Comment: I just realized that you have other parameters in your route. These parameters must be passed to `Url.Action()`. If they are not known at render time, you could provide some dummy values and replace them in JS afterwards.

Comment: Am I not doing that in the "data" line of the AJAX call? BTW, I added an Update 2.

Comment: No, `data` is an additional package of the request. But you want to put these variables into the URL.

Comment: I would say just concatenate the url pieces. Something like `'@Request.Url.Authority' + 'api/' + unitval + '/' + begdateval + '/' + enddateval`

Comment: @MatthewVance: Thanks, I'll try that Monday.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`  
Seems that the answer is a HTML instead a JSON. Check the response from the server to see what are receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with how you are generating the route and how you are trying to access it.

You Web API action is using attribute routing so by default there is no route name to match like in the convention-based routing.

Update the route attribute to include a name to find in the route table.

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class LandingPageController : ApiController {

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{unit}/{begdate}/{enddate}", Name="QuadrantData")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetQuadrantData(string unit, string begdate, string enddate) {
        _unit = unit;
        _beginDate = begdate;
        _endDate = enddate;
        //...other code
    }

    //...other code
}
```

Next even though you have the name you also need to include the template parameters in order to get a match from MVC and have it generate the url in the template you defined on the action.

To generate link to Web API, it would look like this

```
@Url.RouteUrl(routeName : "QuadrantData", routeValues : new { httpRoute = true , unit = "ABUELOS", begdate = "2016-08-07", enddate = "2016-08-13"  })
```

or

```
@Url.HttpRouteUrl(routeName : "QuadrantData", routeValues : new { unit = "ABUELOS", begdate = "2016-08-07", enddate = "2016-08-13"  })
```

which would add the `httpRoute` to the route values.

Reference: [Construct url in view for Web Api with attribute routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186238/construct-url-in-view-for-web-api-with-attribute-routing)

Now with your approach out of the way, I would suggest the following alternative approach.

KISS principle. Change Web API (REST) endpoint to POST and change its template.

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class LandingPageController : ApiController {

    //eg POST api/QuadrantData
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("QuadrantData", Name="GenerateQuadrantData")]
    public HttpResponseMessage QuadrantData(string unit, string begdate, string enddate) {
        _unit = unit;
        _beginDate = begdate;
        _endDate = enddate;
        //...other code
    }

    //...other code
}
```

and send the data in the body of a JSON POST request

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnGetData").click(function () {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
        var unitval = "ABUELOS"; //$('#unitName').val();
        var begdateval = $('#datepickerFrom').val();
        var enddateval = $('#datepickerTo').val();

        var jsonBody = JSON.stringify({ unit: unitval, begdate: begdateval, enddate: enddateval });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.HttpRouteUrl("GenerateQuadrantData", null)',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: jsonBody,
            cache: false,
            success: function (returneddata) {
                alert($(returneddata));
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error in ajax');
            }
        });
    });

}); // end ready function
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally not a big fan of using @Url.Action in javascript code; this is how I make ajax calls:

- Create a hidden field in layout page to store the root url - `<input type="hidden" id="hdnRoot" value="@Url.Content("~/")" />`
- Have a constants json file to keep my client side constants (constants.js) - assigns the hidden field value to `serviceRoot` variable:

  ```
  (function () {
  window.constants = {

      serviceRoot: $("#hdnRoot").val() + "api/",
      objectState: {
          added: "Added",
          modified: "Modified",
          unchanged: "Unchanged",
          deleted: "Deleted"
      },
     ..other values...
  };
  })();
  ```
- Will modify your ajax call as:

  ```
  var root = window.constants.serviceRoot;
  $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: root + 'LandingPage/GetQuadrantData/'+unitval+'/'+begdateval+'/'+enddateval,
            //  data: { unit: unitval, begdate: begdateval, enddate: enddateval },
              contentType: 'application/json',
              cache: false,
              success: function (returneddata) {
              },
              error: function () {
                  alert('hey, boo-boo!');
              }
          });

   [RoutePrefix("api")]
   public class LandingPageController : ApiController {

     [HttpGet]
     [Route("GetQuadrantData/{unit}/{begdate}/{enddate}", Name="GetQuadrantDataFromLandingPage")]
     public HttpResponseMessage GetQuadrantData(string unit, string begdate, string enddate)
  ```

Comment: I don't think I want "LandingPage/GetQuadrantData/"; that's what it is being resolved to, and doesn't work; the URL needs to end up being of the form "/api/<unitname>/<startdate>/<enddate>" such as: "/api/ABUELOS/2016-08-01/2016-08-31"

Comment: @Shannon - my bad, dint notice the api route. You can achieve this in two ways 1. Without changing the api attribute route and have ajax url as `root + LandingPage/GetQuadrantData/<unitname>/<startdate>/<enddate>` 2. Change the api route to just `[Route("GetQuadrantData")]` and keep the ajax call without any change as the data in ajax will be passed as query string and will get bound to action parameters. I would go for the first approach though..

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this solution solves your problem but imply some changes in your code:

In the view, when you call `Url.Action`, you're trying to generate a webapi route from a mvc controller. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36086066/5178207) where I say how to do this.

Basically the idea is using `Url.RouteUrl` with an extra route value `httproute = true`.

Now, you need to change some parts in your code to be able to use this:

Firstly, you are using attributes to define your web api routes, therefore this routes will be added after the routes defined in your `WebApiConfig` class, and as I mencioned in the answer of the referenced question, `Url.RouteUrl` will return the first route that match the route values. So, you need to declare the route in `WebApiConfig` before the default route:

```
/* attributes removed */
public class LandingPageController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage GetQuadrantData(string unit, string begdate, string enddate)
    {
        ...

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        /* Route added before the default one */
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "QuadrantData",
            routeTemplate: "api/{unit}/{begdate}/{enddate}"
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

If you don't do this, the default route will be matched since `{id}` is optional and `unit`, `begdate` and `enddate` will be passed as query params.

Once fixed this issue, you have another problem, to be able to use `Url.RouteUrl` you need to know all the route values (unit, begdate, enddate), that are availables only when the script function is executed. But all razor code in your *.cshtml* is processed in the server when the *html* is generated for the client.

As you can see, when the javascript is executed you are not executing `'@Url.RouteUrl...'` or `'@Url.Action...'`, at this time you are just handling a string with value returned when the razor expression was processed.

One thing you can do is pass "template" values to the `Url.RouteUrl` call, and replace it when the script is executed with the real values:

```
var url = '@Url.RouteUrl(new
      {
          unit = "(unit)",
          begdate = "(begdate)",
          enddate = "(enddate)",
          httproute = true
      })'

url = url.replace("(unit)", unitval)
         .replace("(begdate)", begdateval)
         .replace("(enddate)", enddateval)

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (returneddata) {
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('hey, boo-boo!');
    }
});
```

After the `replace`s the value of the variable `url` will be like this `/api/ABUELOS/2016-08-07/2016-08-13`.

---

If you don't want to move the routes to `WebApiConfig`, you can set a name in `RouteAttribute`:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class LandingPageController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{unit}/{begdate}/{enddate}", Name = "QuadrantData")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetQuadrantData(string unit, string begdate, string enddate)
    {
        ...
```

And specify the route name in `Url.RouteUrl` call:

```
var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("QuadrantData", new
      {
          unit = "(unit)",
          begdate = "(begdate)",
          enddate = "(enddate)",
          httproute = true
      })'
```

This way is less intrusive in your code, but you need to know the name of the route you want to use.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean "Url.RouteUrl" takes the place of "Url.Action" in the ajax call?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: Yes, exactly

Comment: I'm using "HttpResponseMessage" instead of "IHttpActionResult" as the return value of my GetQuadrantData() method in my Controller; is that a problem?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, no, it is not a problem, when I was working on it I changed it to return another value. I just forgot to change it back in the answer. Just a moment.

Comment: NKosi's answer worked; it was the easiest. Thanks for your help, though; I'm sure your way would have worked, too, if I would have spent more time on it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your point:

> If I manually enter that URL in the browser, so that the URL bar reads
>   "http://localhost:52194/api/ABUELOS/2016-08-21/2016-08-27" it works -
>   the method is reached and it "does its thing."

Modifying your Ajax call like shown below should solve your problem and will send a GET request to the mapped url (**Showing with button click event handler**):

```
 $("#btnGetData").click(function () {

   var unitval = 'ABUELOS';
   var begdateval = '2016-08-21';
   var enddateval = '2016-08-27';

   $.getJSON("api/" + unitval + "/" + begdateval + "/" + enddateval,
      function (Data) {
        // do what ever you want with the success response
      })
      .fail(
        function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
          // do what ever you want with the failed response
      });
 });
```

Comment: I still make it to the "fail" part of the house with your code.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon i have tested this code with your problem mentioned and it works with your mapped Route.
Could you please mention what is the failed part you have found?

Comment: NKosi's answer worked; it was the easiest. Thanks for your help, though; I'm sure your way would have worked, too, if I would have spent more time on it.

Answer (score -1):

You're only giving your jQuery the controller and action names when it needs the full url to complete the request.  Also, your end point has an 'api' prefix.  You need your url property to be something like http://localhost:{port}/api/{controller}/{action} if your server is running locally.

Comment: This is what `Url.Action()` is supposed to return.

Comment: It's only running locally for now; are you saying that the the line should be something like this:
url: '@Url.Action("http://localhost:52194/api/ABUELOS/2016-08-21/2016-08-27") or ...
?

Comment: should be something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19868321/3573527) answer